# 1st DIV element causes content inside 2nd DIV Element with 100% Height to be pushed off screen

Tags: css, html

I read a lot of the other questions but can't figure out how to work the solutions into my issue.

Having my main content DIV at 100% height works perfectly fine except when adding another element outside of the DIV and towards the top of the browser. The DIV with 100% retains the full height of the browser and does not take into consideration the new element at the top of the browser. This causes content at the bottom of the DIV to be pushed out of view.

Details:

1. One required outcome is for no browser scroll bars to be placed.
2. In Production it is a DIV containing a FLASH object that is 100% width and Height of the Browser.
3. Not entirely sure which HTML version is best to use for embedding FLASH. Although if necessary I can figure this out with another question.

JSFiddle Code Example:

1. [This Shows how the Blue content box should appear normally](http://jsfiddle.net/fk6HT/1/)

   ```
     body {
       background-color: #FFFFFF;

       height: auto;

       margin: 0;

       min-height: 100%;

       overflow: hidden;

   }

   #logo {
       background-color: #000000;
       height: 40px;
       width: 100px;
       display: none;
   }

   #panel-1 {
       background-color: #CCCCCC;
       display: block;
       height: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%;
   }

   #panel-content {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCFFEE;
       bottom: 0;
       height: 50px;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
   }
   <div>
   <div id="header">
       <div id="logo"></div>
   </div>
   <div style="" id="content-wrapper">
       <div id="panel-1">
           <div id="panel-content"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. [This Shows what happens to the blue box at the bottom when an element is added to the top](http://jsfiddle.net/fk6HT/)

   ```
     body {
       background-color: #FFFFFF;
       height: auto;
       margin: 0;
       min-height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

   #logo {
       background-color: #000000;
       height: 40px;
       width: 100px;

   }

   #panel-1 {
       background-color: #CCCCCC;
       display: block;
       height: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%;

   }

   #panel-content {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCFFEE;
       bottom: 0;
       height: 50px;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
   }
   <div>
   <div id="header">
       <div id="logo"></div>
   </div>
   <div style="" id="content-wrapper">
       <div id="panel-1">
           <div id="panel-content"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: 100% plus something will always be more than 100%...

Comment: lol yeah. The problem is I am trying to figure out how to take up 100% of the remaining space after the top element is taken into consideration. Have not been able to figure this out.

Comment: Why not put it inside the 100% height element?

Comment: I tried because it caused the same issue with the 100% height flash object within the 100% height element. The answer from @Gimmy appears to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/auAfu/) your desired solution?:

Html:

```
<div>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="panel-1">
            <div id="panel-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#logo
{
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
}
#panel-1
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#panel-content
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCFFEE;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! I had to change height: calc(100% - 50px); to height: calc(100% - 40px); though as 50 caused a white space on the bottom of the browser. Do you have a good reference for using "calc" ? I've never used it before and haven't seen anyone mention it in other 100% height related issues.

Comment: Here is a list of browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/calc. And here is w3.org page: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#calc-notation As it seems, it is yet only a 'Candidate Recommendation' for CSS standard. Not yet a standard.